# How to test Exceptions (Query and DML) for ContentDocument?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, exception, queryexception

I try to write wrong query, but I get just error un my test, not coverage. If I use try-catch in unit-test - no error and no coverage either. How to test it right? And how can I test here delete DML Exception? Thanks for any help.

Class:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {}
public ContentDocument cd;

public void deletePreviousFiles(List<Id> toolsRecordId) {
    List<ContentVersion> cvList = getContentVersionList(toolsRecordId);
    List<ContentDocument> cdList = new List <ContentDocument>();

    for(ContentVersion cv : cvList){
        try{
            cd = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id =: cv.ContentDocumentId];
            cdList.add(cd);
        //No coverage here:
        } catch(QueryException e){
            throw new MyException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    try{
        delete cdList;
    //No coverage here:
    } catch(Exception e){
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Test:

```
Tool__c tool = new Tool__c;
insert tool;
List<Id> toolsRecordIds = new List<Id>{ tool.Id };

Test.startTest();
    List<Tool__c> toolList = myClass.getTools();
    List<ContentVersion> contentVersionList = myClass.getCVList(toolsRecordIds);

    //And I get here 'System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject':
    myClass.cd = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = 'a071r00001JcCaHAAV'];  //wrong Id is here
    myClass.deletePreviousFiles(toolsRecordIds);
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchResume(), 1);
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: There are a few things a bit off on this code. SOQLs in a for loop is not a good practice. Don't understand why you use two try/catch/ blocks there. You could use just one. The Test class is a bit confusing as well. I think that you nee to take a look to best practices structures for your test class.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you are making SOQL inside for loop. Which is a bigger issue then the try catch block exception in test class. So I suggest you to first work on that.

After you have fixed that then you need to check that is it really necessary to add a try-catch block here, Will this code ever throw an exception? unnecessary try catch just increases lines of code.

Now coming to your point in the first block you are storing in a variable so if your list doesn't return any data in that case you will get an exception "List has no row assignment to sObject" you can try to generate that.

In second try-catch unless you are checking something and preventing the deletion its hard to generate error there so you can write some code in `Test.isRunningTest()` block to generate custom exception. May not be the perfect solution but will work.

Comment: 1. "so if your list doesn't return any data" - Well, I try to do that in my test. But it's brings me back just error. How to do it right?

2. I always think that all query and dml operations should be in try/catch blocks. Why we can't check delete?

Comment: @MichaelLev19 1. Not clear on your first point. 2. Try-catch on Query is not needed unless you are making dynamic SOQL without verifying user inputs. DML we should include in try-catch but delete is special case, in only few case(eg: Some rule preventing deletion, dependency error) we can generate/ get exception. You need to check this.